# Transition from background to foreground mode is random in AltBeacon

Tags: android, altbeacon

OK. I Have been lately working on an indoor geolocation application using [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) library.
Everything seems to work right except for the transition from background to the foreground which takes random intervals of time and is not fast enough.
In my code, as the application is running in the background, when a beacon is detected, it doesn't immediately switch to the foreground to show some events.
I need to know the cause of this latency and the randomness. And if possible how to fix it.

The main activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    BeaconManager beaconManager; 
    BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
    Region region;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        region = new Region("com.example.backgroundRegion",
                Identifier.parse("3d4f13b4-d1fd-4049-80e5-d3edcc840b6a"), null, null); // list of 3 identifiers
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        // set the duration of the scan to be 1.1 seconds
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2000l); 
        //beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);// because setBackgroundScanPeriods calls background mode automatically
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        beaconManager.bind(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {

        // if (haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);

        //   }
        //   haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;

    }


    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("tag","I no longer see a beacon in the "+region.getUniqueId());
    }


    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        // release whatever is needed
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
        beaconManager = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //Scan lasts for SCAN_PERIOD time
            beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(3000l);
            //Wait every SCAN_PERIOD_INBETWEEN time
            beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
            //Update default time with the new one
            beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(Beacon b: beacons)
        {
            Log.d("tag","beacon name  "+b.getBluetoothName());
            Log.d("tag","beacon rssi  "+b.getRssi());
            Log.d("tag","beacon uuid  "+Integer.toString(b.getServiceUuid()));
            Log.d("tag","beacon address "+b.getBluetoothAddress());
            Log.d("tag","beacon distance "+b.getDistance());

        }

    }

 }
```

The manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidbeacon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Test"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the Test class..

```
public class Test extends Activity{
    TextView txt1;
    TextView txt2;
    TextView txt3;
    @Override
    protected
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate()` does not call `beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod()`, so the BeaconManager is using the default setting of 5 minutes. If you want your background-to-foreground transitions to be more predictable, you need to set the between-scan period to something much lower -- but that would also mean that the battery life will be shorter.

Comment: even if I add it I still have the same problem :/